# How to resolve ValueError in following code?

Tags: python, csv, exception, valueerror

The votes are in… and it's up to you to make sure the correct winner is announced!

You've been given a CSV file called nominees.csv, which contains the names of various movies nominated for a prize, and the people who should be announced as the recipient. The file will look like this:

```
title,director(s)
Schindler's List,Steven Spielberg
"O Brother, Where Art Thou?","Joel Coen, Ethan Coen"
2001: A Space Odyssey,Stanley Kubrick
"Sherlock, Jr.","Buster Keaton, Roscoe Arbuckle"
```

You should write a program that reads in nominees.csv, asks for the name of the winning title, and prints out specific congratulations. For example, with the above file, your program should work like this:

```
Winning title: O Brother, Where Art Thou?
Congratulations: Joel Coen, Ethan Coen
```

Here is another example, using the same file:

```
Winning title: Schindler's List
Congratulations: Steven Spielberg
```

Already tried submitting and altering values but line number 10 always gives value error and so does line number 15. When a list of new nominees is applied, it gives the error and fails my code.

```
def main():
  film_director=[]
  with open('nominees.csv','r') as read_file:
    lines=read_file.readlines()
    lines=lines[1:]
  for line in lines:
    if '"' in line:
      if line[0]=='"':
        index_second_quotes=line.index('"',1)
        index_third_quotes=line.index('"',index_second_quotes+1)
        title = line[:index_second_quotes].strip('\"')
        directors=line[index_third_quotes:-1].strip('\"').strip()
      else:
        index_first_quotes = line.index('"')
        index_second_quotes = line.index('"', index_first_quotes+1)
        title = line[:index_first_quotes-1].strip('\"')
        directors = line[index_first_quotes+1:-1].strip('\"').strip()
      film_director.append([title,directors])
    else:
        tokens = line.split(',')
        film_director.append([tokens[0].strip(),tokens[1].strip()])
  title = input('Winning title: ')

  for row in film_director:
    if title.strip()==row[0]:
      print('Congratulations:',row[1])
      break

main()
```

The error message given is:

```
Testing a new nominees file. Your submission raised an exception of type ValueError. This occurred on line 10 of program.py.
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Not a homework problem. Improving python skills but stuck on this one for the last 3 hours. Would aprreciate help or solution. Thanks

Comment: By the way, your code works fine: https://repl.it/repls/FairBraveLaw

Comment: Is this an online test site? Is it supposed to run on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: it is suppose to run on python 3

Comment: It works fine on Python 3 as can be seen from the link I posted. Probably that test site is broken.

Comment: It highlights the +1 on the index_second_qoutes line maybe that is the issue. The input and output are still correct and it gives me that but it fails that part of the code,

Answer (score 0):

The above number of condition checks, splitting, concatenation can be omitted with regular expression. You can make use of the below code with a single regular expression and a split

```
import re
with open("nominees.csv") as cf:
    lines = cf.readlines()

for line in lines[1:]:
    reg_match = re.match(r'"([^""]*)","([^""]*)"$', line)
    if reg_match:
        win_title, director = reg_match.group(1), reg_match.group(2)
    else:
        win_title, director = line.split(",")
    print("Winning title: %s" % win_title)
    print("Congratulations: %s" % director.strip())
```

Comment: What is "re.match". It tells me that name re is not defined

Comment: import re, add this at the top. You need to import package re, which is the regular expression package in python

Comment: Now it prints all of them. I just need directors for corresponding input of winning title.